# Updating each row on iteration - logical structure assitance

Tags: php, mysql

I need assitance to figure out this problem. I tried to simplify thing as possible. There aren't any errors, it's just a matter of accessing that I can't afford to figure out.

Imagine :

```
<?php
   for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
   ?>
    Member:
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo trim("member_".$i);?>" />
    <br/>
   <?php
   } ?>
```

The above codes generates :

```
<input name="member_1">
 <input name="member_2">
 <input name="member_3">
```

and now assuming, the data in table

```
org_ID (Foreign Key)    member
A                          1
A                          2
A                          3
```

Now come to update function :

```
public function updateTo($tableName, $org_D,$member) {
        try {
            $stm = "update " . $tableName . " SET member = :member WHERE org_D= :org_D";
            $eksekutor = $this->koneksi->prepare($stm);
            $eksekutor->bindValue(":org_D",  $org_D, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $eksekutor->bindValue(":member ", $member, PDO::PARAM_STR);
             $eksekutor->execute();
            $done = true;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $done = false;
        }
        return $done;
    }
```

and finally the update operation :

*If I do this* (*which is wrong since it keeps updating all row for each iteration*):

```
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
    $member = $_POST["member_$i"];
    $update = $kad->updateTo("table_name", $org_D,  $member);
}
```

I need help, I can't afford to figure out how to achive this update operation:

```
$_POST["member_1"]; ------ UPDATE TO-------> row "member" contains 1
$_POST["member_2"]; ------ UPDATE TO-------> row "member" contains 2
$_POST["member_3"]; ------ UPDATE TO-------> row "member" contains 3
```

since in update operation I've to decide value for each *`WHERE=`*

Comment: You are updating `member` column with the value coming from `<input name="member_1">` but how do you know the previous value for that member? Can you post your entire form not just only that loop part ? There must be a relation between the form field with the new member value and the old member value to update. Or you can use other column value in another related form field to identify which record to update.

Comment: Basically the number of values *to be* updated is *same* with the number of previous inserted values, I want everythings is just to be got overrided. If you see `SET member = :member WHERE org_D= :org_D and whatrow=?"` <-- this exatcly my point, but If I can't find any solutions I will go for extracting all `member` row, then just ovveride it.

Comment: Values for `whatrow=?` must be known before submitting the form and passed perhaps as hidden form fields. And then adjust WHERE clause in your update function. This assumes `whatrow` uniquely identifies any row. Apparently in your logic you are using `member` as the column to update and the column to see which row to update. Is that correct?

Comment: *"This assumes whatrow uniquely identifies any row"* <-- yeap that's my point, the whole point is to just update all rows without extracting/retrieving the old/previous values (that already exist in db), because the number of loops will remain the same so it makes think  that there's somehow another structure I can construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your sending the same UPDATE statement to you database in each iteration. If you want to update a single member per iteration you'll have to add that to your WHERE clause.

Maybe you have something more to reference a member than given in your example. Otherwise you'll have to add the previous member-value to your where clause.

```
public function updateTo($tableName, $org_D, $prevMember, $newMember) {
    ...
    $stm = "update " . $tableName . " SET member= :newMember WHERE org_D=:org_D AND member = :prevMember";
    $eksekutor = $this->koneksi->prepare($stm);
    $eksekutor->bindValue(":org_D",  $org_D, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $eksekutor->bindValue(":newMember", $newMember, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $eksekutor->bindValue(":prevMember", $prevMember, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ya, this "prevMember" is the one making me buggy.., how to decide it. The only things now comes to my mind is to extract previous values.

Comment: Well I don't know your situation, but when building a form to update these values, you must have these values at hand. Don't you?

Comment: Exactly, but let me wait for any other suggestions, I'll upvote you later but not now, I promise.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of your `WHERE` condition. See here,

```
...WHERE org_D= :org_D";
```

Since you're passing `A`, your `org_D`, as an argument to the method, it's updating all three rows in each iteration of `for` loop. You need to pass the current member's id to the `updateTo()` method as well.

So, first change your `for` loop in the following fashion,

```
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
    $member = $_POST["member_$i"];
    $update = $kad->updateTo("table_name", $i+1, $org_D,  $member);
}
```

And then change the `updateTo()` method in the following way,

```
public function updateTo($tableName, $oldMemberId, $org_D, $newMemberId) {
    try {
        $stm = "update " . $tableName . " SET member = :newMemberId WHERE member = :oldMemberId AND org_D= :org_D";
        $eksekutor = $this->koneksi->prepare($stm);
        $eksekutor->bindValue(":newMemberId ", $newMemberId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $eksekutor->bindValue(":oldMemberId ", $oldMemberId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $eksekutor->bindValue(":org_D",  $org_D, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $eksekutor->execute();
        $done = true;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $done = false;
    }
    return $done;
}
```

Comment: The only way to get the `:oldMemberId` is by extracting the old values. This would be the very last try of me. But In your humble opinion, can I somehow modify my structure to prevent extracting the old values? If no then I guess there won't be any alternatives for me :D

Comment: @Hey-men-whatsup Oh, I thought that's your original table, that's why I pass `$i+1` as member's id in each iteration of `for` loop. And to answer your question, yes, you have to somehow extract member's id(old) and pass them to your `updateTo()` method, otherwise the `UPDATE` operation won't happen correctly.

Comment: Hmm. no choices I'll extract the previous values, btw *sAimon.ro* answered first, but I'' upvote you . Thank you so much for the help